# UIRefreshControl change color of UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, colors, uiactivityindicatorview, uirefreshcontrol

There is any way to change the color of the "UIActivityIndicatorView" of the UIRefreshControl??

I didn't find anything!

Thanks!!

[image: UIRefreshControl]

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know... but take a look at some custom classes, maybe you'll find something of use in there that shows how it's done: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=indicator

Answer (score 27):

You can do it by setting the `Tint Color` of the `UIRefreshControl`, something like this:

**Objective C**
`[refreshControl setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];`

**Swift**
`refreshControl.tintColor = .black`

This will  also change the arrow that expands when you slide.

Answer (score 7):

As the previous answer is outdated, I thought that I would just modify it to Swift 4 and share the solution (credit goes to @subharb).

```
refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

This line of code will change the color of the UIActivityIndicatorView to whatever color you want it to be :)